# Adding a variable into Keras/TensorFlow CNN dense layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I was wondering if it is possible to add a variable into a convolutional neural network's dense layer (so as well as the connections from the previous convolutional layers, there would be an additional feature set that could be used for discriminatory purposes)? If this is possible, can anyone point me to an example/documentation explaining how to do so?

I am hoping to use Keras, but am happy to use TensorFlow if Keras is too restrictive.

EDIT: In this case, the way that I would think that this should work is that I provide a list containing images and associated feature sets to the neural network (and during training the associated classifications).

EDIT2: The architecture that I want looks something like:

```
              ___________      _________      _________      _________     ________    ______
              | Conv    |     | Max    |     | Conv    |     | Max    |    |       |   |     |
    Image --> | Layer 1 | --> | Pool 1 | --> | Layer 2 | --> | Pool 2 | -->|       |   |     |
              |_________|     |________|     |_________|     |________|    | Dense |   | Out |
                                                                           | Layer |-->|_____|
   Other      ------------------------------------------------------------>|       |
   Data                                                                    |       |
                                                                           |_______|
```

Comment: What is the architecture that you are trying to build? I'm not sure to understand your question

Comment: @NassimBen I've added the desired architecture now! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, as @Marcin said, you can use a merge layer.

I advise you to use the Functionnal API for this. If you're not familiar with it, read [some doc here](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

Here is your doodled network model using the keras API :

```
from keras.layers.core import *
from keras.models import Model

# this is your image input definition. You have to specify a shape. 
image_input = Input(shape=(32,32,3))
# Some more data input with 10 features (eg.)
other_data_input = Input(shape=(10,))    

# First convolution filled with random parameters for the example
conv1 = Convolution2D(nb_filter = nb_filter1, nb_row = nb_row1, nb_col=_nb_col1, padding = "same", activation = "tanh")(image_input)
# MaxPool it 
conv1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_1,pool_2))(conv1)
# Second Convolution
conv2 = Convolution2D(nb_filter = nb_filter2, nb_row = nb_row2, nb_col=_nb_col2, padding = "same", activation = "tanh")(conv1)
# MaxPool it
conv2  = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_1,pool_2))(conv2)
# Flatten the output to enable the merge to happen with the other input
first_part_output = Flatten()(conv2)

# Merge the output of the convNet with your added features by concatenation
merged_model = keras.layers.concatenate([first_part_output, other_data_input])

# Predict on the output (say you want a binary classification)
predictions = Dense(1, activation ='sigmoid')(merged_model)

# Now create the model
model = Model(inputs=[image_input, other_data_input], outputs=predictions)
# see your model 
model.summary()

# compile it
model.compile(optimizer='adamax', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

There you go :) It is quite easy in the end, define how many inputs and outputs you want, just specify them in a list when you create the `Model` object. When you fit it, also feed them separately, in a list.

Comment: Thank you so much; this is incredibly helpful!

Comment: When training this model using `.fit` the loss remains constant over all epochs? Do you have any idea why this could be?

Comment: I'll edit, the mistakes comes from the activation of the last layer. Use sigmoid over 1 output or 'softmax' over 2 outputs. see the edit :)

Comment: This seems to work for the first few epochs. Then I end up getting stuck, so a sample output would be: 
`Epoch 1/20
960/960 [==============================] - 38s - loss: 3.2810 - val_loss: 10.0558
Epoch 2/20
960/960 [==============================] - 41s - loss: 2.7194 - val_loss: 0.0083
Epoch 3/20
960/960 [==============================] - 40s - loss: 2.3085 - val_loss: 16.1181
Epoch 4/20
960/960 [==============================] - 42s - loss: 6.0443 - val_loss: 16.1181
Epoch 7/20
960/960 [==============================] - 43s - loss: 6.0443 - val_loss: 16.1181`

Comment: that can be a data/problem formulation/solution architecture issue... I can not really help you with that unfortunately. This is specific to your problem...

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! Just a quick question, is it common for the loss to decrease and then suddenly start to increase? For instance, it seems that at first the training is working towards a minimum and then it starts to increase on every epoch. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's maybe an issue with the learning rate, but I doubt it because adamax should have an adaptative learning rate. It is a symptom of unstability somewhere... maybe post this issue in stat/ML stack website, with complete description of your data and what you are trying to predict :) It is a "common" issue but it can come from a lot of possible mistakes or specificities of your problem.

Comment: To update the answer to comply with Keras 2 API, replace `merged_model` declaration by `keras.layers.concatenate([first_part_output, other_data_input])` and rename `input` argument of `Model()` to `inputs`.

Comment: Also, `border_mode` of `Convolution2D` needs to be renamed to `padding` and `output` of `Model` needs to be renamed to `outputs` to get rid of all the warnings.

Comment: Thank you ! added the modifications

Answer (score 1):

Ok, assuming that you have the `convoluton_model` you could do this in a following manner:

```
convolution_model = Flatten()(convolution_model) # if it wasn't flattened before
static_features_input = Input(shape=(static_features_size,))
blended_features = merge([convolution_model, static_features_input], mode='concat')
... here you are defining a blending model with blended features as input
```

[Here](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models) you could find an example on how to merge different inputs.